# upgrade wms tiles to openlayers 4.6.5

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to gradually upgrade from version 4.4 to version 6 of openlayers.
This wms tiles layer works in 4.4 but not in 4.6.5.
do you know why please ?

```
//couche géologique brgm
    //la source
    var geolSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://geoservices.brgm.fr/WMS-C/?',
        params: {
            LAYERS: 'GeologieJPG',
            TILED: true,
            FORMAT: 'image/jpeg',
        },
        extent: [40428, 1600797, 1216896, 2698833.8],
        resolutions: [1056.633663, 528.3168317, 264.1584158, 132.0792079, 66.03960396, 26.41584158, 13.229166668, 6.614583334, 2.645833334],
        projection: "EPSG:27582",
        transitionEffect: 'resize',
        reproject: true,
        crossOrigin: "Anonymous"
    });
    //le layer
    var geol = new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: false,
        source: geolSource,
        name: 'Carte géologique',
        description: "Carte géologique, url=http://geoservices.brgm.fr/WMS-C/?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities, couche GeologieJPG"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get that code to work with 4.4.  It should work with any version if you replace the `extent` and `resolutions` options with

```
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
      extent: [40428, 1600797, 1216896, 2698833.8],
      resolutions: [1056.633663, 528.3168317, 264.1584158, 132.0792079, 66.03960396, 26.41584158, 13.229166668, 6.614583334, 2.645833334],
      origin: [40428, 1600797]
    }),
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.4/proj4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
    proj4.defs("EPSG:27582","+proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=2200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs");
    var geolSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'https://geoservices.brgm.fr/WMS-C/?',
        params: {
            LAYERS: 'GeologieJPG',
            TILED: true,
            FORMAT: 'image/jpeg',
        },
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
          extent: [40428, 1600797, 1216896, 2698833.8],
          resolutions: [1056.633663, 528.3168317, 264.1584158, 132.0792079, 66.03960396, 26.41584158, 13.229166668, 6.614583334, 2.645833334],
          origin: [40428, 1600797]
        }),
        projection: "EPSG:27582",
        transitionEffect: 'resize',
        reproject: true,
        crossOrigin: "Anonymous"
    });

    var geol = new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: true,
        source: geolSource,
        name: 'Carte géologique',
        description: "Carte géologique, url=http://geoservices.brgm.fr/WMS-C/?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities, couche GeologieJPG"
    });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
           source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          geol
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: "EPSG:3857",
          center: [269269.603, 5953355.405],
          zoom: 5.5
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the try but it doesnt work

Comment: I've added a working example, the problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: in fact it is displayed but in Africa instead of France
there must be a coordinate problem

Comment: the map is in 3857

Comment: I have changed mine to 3857 and added a background layer - the geology is in France

Comment: I don't understand why there is this discrepancy
I can't put a picture to show it

Comment: //le centre et la vue par défaut
 var center = [269269.603, 5953355.405];
 var zoom = 5.5;
//la map carte : projection par défaut EPSG:3857
 var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([dragAndDropInteraction]), //on rajoute le dragAndDropInteraction
  layers: [],
  view: new ol.View({
  //projection: "EPSG:3857",
   center: center,
   zoom: zoom
  })
 });

Comment: I have changed my center and zoom to match that.  Have you included the proj4 definition for EPSG:27582 ?

Comment: ok with proj4 it works
in the OL4.4 it was not necessary
Thanks a lot Mike